# iptables, rpcbind, nfs (v4) - vagrant cannot mount

Tags: iptables, nfs, vagrant

## The setup

- debian 9.6
- vagrant 2.2.3
- VMs are all configured in vagrant as private network with static IPv4 in address space "192.168.3.0/24"
- as far as I discovered NFSv4 and later is listening to TCP:2049 only

`Vagrantfile` (extraction)

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.3.123"
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"
```

`iptables -L -n -v`

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 393 packets, 65897 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 8629 1377K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.3.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:111
  266 22344 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       192.168.3.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:111
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.3.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:2049
 526K 1066M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 600 packets, 37554 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 353K   36M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

`ip6tables -L -n -v`

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   33  6015 ACCEPT     all      lo     *       ::/0                 ::/0                
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 tcp dpt:22
    1   601 ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   25  5204 ACCEPT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

## The question

Without the rules the mounts are going well. So what I'm not aware of or what am I missing to get the mounts working?

Comment: It would be interesting showing us the actual iptables rules, besides stats. Have you also tried to debug the situation using `tcpdump` with and without firewalling?

Answer (score 0):

I would connect to the remote machine by the intended means without the rules in place and find out what ports are actually being used by that method:

`netstat -vatn` for open TCP

`netstat -vaun` for open UDP

`lsof -i` list open ports

Then make the appropriate rule based on what is listed for the process you want.

This website maybe helpful: [Iptable Essentials](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands)